# Getting Post angular 2 toPromise HTTP

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http

Hello I need to get some response after posting json object, using toPromise, its my code, respond is undefined:

```
export class ApiStorage{
constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http ){}
    rs(){
    this.http.post('http://0.0.0.0:80/student/outbound', this.json, headers)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                respond = JSON.stringify(response);
                return respond; //<- edited
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
            ...
                });
    }
}
```

then when in main component I use

```
send(){
    respondJSON = apistorage.rs();
    console.log(respondJSON);
    }
```

respondJSON is undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`respond` will always be undefined in your code, because you are making an asynchronous call to a webservice, which you do not await before logging to console.

```
export class ApiStorage{

    constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http ){}

    rs() {

        return this.http.post('http://0.0.0.0:80/student/outbound', this.json, headers)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                let respond = JSON.stringify(response));
                return respond;
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                ...
            });
    }
}

// rs now returns a promise, which can be used like this
// inside another function
send() {
    apistorage.rs().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: But can you help me again and tell how to return respond? When I use respond = JSON.stringify(response));
 return respond; // <- this returns nothing

Comment: Can you please post a new question for this and show some more of your code, so that we can see the context? Would be easier to help.

Comment: How do you call this function? Where should it return to? Can you also show some of that code, please?